# String para Array/List

Tags: java, array, string

Tenho a seguinte String:

```
[{"Monstro":"Lobo","HP":100,"Level":2},{"Level":"1","HP":"100","Monstro":"Bruxa"}]
```

E preciso coloca-la dentro de uma `Array ou List` para pegar os valores de cada monstro.

- **Como eu faço isso?**

Desculpe caso a dúvida pareça óbvia.

<sub>**OBS**: são dados de *JSON* que estão dentro dos `[…]` normal do jeito que esta e tem a `},{` vigula entre eles que seprar os 2 valores diferentes que estão dentro dos `[...]`.</sub>

Comment: A melhor forma de fazer isso é criando uma classe e dando parse no json para um objeto da classe. Tem certeza que você deseja fazer assim?

Comment: sim eu usso a api org.json que não tem suporte ao parce e estou fazendo ums testes antes de montar eu mesmo essa parte da api. aproveitando como um desafio a min mesmo.

Comment: Precisa ser um array? Não pode utilizar `List`?

Comment: @Renan pode ser qualquer forma que de para eu escolher qual dos dois dados pegar.

Comment: OK, seu JSON está errado assim mesmo ou foi na hora de passar aqui para a pergunta? Existem chaves diferentes nos objetos `Monstro` e `Monstro:`.

Comment: @Renan nem percebi vou arrumar tive que digitar td ja que o ctrl+c/ctrl+v ta bugado no meu teclado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu seguiria a mesma ideia do [comentário do @Francisco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/259877/string-para-array-list?noredirect=1#comment533010_259877), criar um objeto que mapeasse os atributos do monstro: `nome`, `hitpoints` e `level`, ainda que não fosse utilizá-los por hora em minha aplicação. Mas, se o objetivo é somente obter todos os valores da chave `Monstro`, pode fazer assim:

```
public final List<String> getMonstros(String json){
    List<String> monsters = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        new JSONArray(json).forEach(item -> {

            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) item;
            if(object.has("Monstro"))
                monsters.add(object.getString("Monstro"));

        });  
    } catch(Exception ex){
        // Tratamento de exceção.
    }
    return monsters;
}
```

```
final String json = "[{\"Monstro\":\"Lobo\",\"HP\":100,\"Level\":2}, {\"Level\":\"1\",\"HP\":\"100\",\"Monstro\":\"Bruxu\"}]";
System.out.println(getMonstros(json)); // [Lobo, Bruxu]
```

Comment: sua resposta me deu uma ideia se usar esse mesmo codigo trocando `if(object.has("Monstro"))
                monsters.add(object.getString("Monstro"));` por `f(object.has("hp"))
                monsters.add(object.getString("hp"));` ele retorna na ordem?se ele retornar na ordem ja tenho uma ideia de como fazer o parcer do org.json

Comment: Ele nem funcionaria pois o atributo `HP` está em maiúsculo e é um tipo inteiro, teria que usar `object.getInt("HP")`. Mesmo assim, não retornaria em ordem (nem esse da minha resposta retorna ordenado), teria que utilizar o método [`Collections#sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) para isto. E claro, ao invés de uma lista de strings, seria uma lista de inteiros.

Comment: então não retorna na ordem que esta na String do json?

Comment: to recebendo erro no `forEach`

Comment: Não, retornou em ordem porque a string está com os atributos `Lobo` e `Bruxu` em sequência. Qual erro está dando no `forEach`? Qual versão do Java está rodando?

Comment: java: `jdk1.8.0_151, jre1.8.0_151 forEach erro:cannot find symbol` e na hora de dar println da o erro:  `non-static method getMonstros(String) cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: vou ter que desligar o pc agora amanha vejo se resolvo, se tiver discord add#1011

Comment: Provavelmente você está chamando o método `getMonstros()` de um método estático. Basta mudar para `public static final Lista<String> getMonstros()`.

Comment: agora so ta dando o erro do forEach

Comment: Qual erro.... ?

Comment: dx quieto arrumei uma outra forma para fazer isso vlw pela ajuda